# Comments don't highlight spaces in code over newlines

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, markdown, code-formatting

I recently noticed that comments don't highlight spaces over newlines in code blocks.

For example, I posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15075895/722121) containing `", ".join()`, and then, when displayed, it looked like this:

[image: Screenshot of missing space.]

As you can see, the space is not highlighted correctly - when copy/pasted, the space is there, but this does change how it looks.

Not a vital thing, but thought it was worth a mention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a problem with Stack Overflow. Code highlighted using the `<code>` HTML tag, which is an **inline-level element**. This means that it will line-wrap when possible (Spaces are those "seams" where a line-wrap can occur).

There's nothing much to be done, and frankly, I don't think that anything *should* be done. It's quite an edge case. Just edit your comment a little bit and it'll display fine.

Comment: I'm familiar with the reason for this - that doesn't mean there is no work-around to have it display correctly (even something as simple as converting spaces into non-breaking spaces, for example - although that could cause larger layout issues). This said it is obviously, as you say, a pretty small bug so it wouldn't necessarily be worthwhile.

Comment: If you convert spaces into NBSPs, copy-pasting the code will fail on any compiler. Hene, the solution isn't viable.

Comment: That's very true - it was also a bad idea for other reasons - I was just making the point there is the potential for a fix here, just because this is the way HTML works, doesn't mean that there is nothing that can be done to make it more suitable for this need.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that would fix this is replacing spaces with `&nbsp;` (non-breaking spaces), which would cause the entire thing to stay together and thus keep the space visible. However, longer blocks of code then would never break and would extend past the screen, because there are never any breaking points in it.

An alternate way is to *add* `&nbsp;` before the actual space, without removing the space itself, which would show the physical space there while still wrapping on the regular space. It would be visually pleasing, *but* copying and pasting the code like that would render two spaces in the text.

Browsers wrap spaces like that, it's how they're designed. So, there's really nothing we *can* do about it without an extraordinary amount of work, and that amount of work just isn't feasible for something as minor as this.

Comment: Like I said in a comment on my answer. If you use an `&nbsp;` instead of spaces, the code becomes uncopypastable. It won't compile or work anymore.